# Swift Update label with Parse object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uilabel

I am trying to update a label with the contents of a parse object. This does not work.

```
if let userPoints = PFUser.currentUser()?["points"] as? String {
        self.userPointsLabel.text = userPoints
    }
```

This here works though

```
if let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"] as? String {
        self.userNameLabel.text = "@" + pUserName
    }
```

The points column is in the users class, so I do not see why this does not work.

Comment: Does the points column contain a string? you are trying to parse it as a string and if it's not it might fail, no?

Comment: @Moriya I know. It is a number.  When I set it to Int I get an error though

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Moriya when I set it to as? Int I get "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String?' ", and it highlights userPoints

Comment: You need to include the int in a string to set it in the label. I wrote an answer that should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast and Int? to String? and that fails so the if statement will never be true.

You want to parse the points value as an Int and then use it as a string

```
if let userPoints = PFUser.currentUser()?["points"] as? Int {
   self.userPointsLabel.text = "\(userPoints)"
}
```